# What does this mean? this['find'](function(model){ ... })

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was trying to understand how the Backbone Collection `findWhere()` function works, and I saw this in the code:

```
    // Return models with matching attributes. Useful for simple cases of
    // `filter`.
    where: function(attrs, first) {
      var matches = _.matches(attrs);
      return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
        return matches(model.attributes);
      });
    },

    // Return the first model with matching attributes. Useful for simple cases
    // of `find`.
    findWhere: function(attrs) {
      return this.where(attrs, true);
    },
```

I'm trying to understand what this part does:

```
  return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
    return matches(model.attributes);
  });
```

What does this part  `this['find'](function(model){ ... })` actually do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bracket notation instead of dot notation in javascript and the bracket notation is very handy in such case like you're having. So, the following are the same:

```
foo.['bar']
foo.bar()
```

---

In this line:

```
return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
```

`this.find()` would be used if first value returns true else `this.filter()` would be used.

Answer (score 1):

It goes like this

- `this` is a `Object`
- `[first ? 'find' : 'filter']` checks if bool `first` is positive, then return `'find'` else `'filter'` which are function references accessed by bracket notation `[]`. In short usage of ternary operator to access a function reference by bracker notation.
- `(...){}` is invocation of that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
this['find'](function(model){ ... })
```

This part is equal to:

```
this.find(function(model){ ... })
```

So the answer: it is method `find` of object `this` is being called with parameter (I assume it is callback :) ) `function(model){ ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
return this[first ? 'find' : 'filter'](function(model) {
    return matches(model.attributes);
});
```

Is the same as

```
var functionName = (first ? 'find' : 'filter');
return this[functionName](function(model) {
    return matches(model.attributes);
});
```

Which is the same as

```
var functionName;
if(first){
    functionName = 'find';
} else {
    functionName = 'filter';
}
return this[functionName](function(model) {
    return matches(model.attributes);
});
```

Which is the same as

```
if(first){
    return this['find'](function(model) {
        return matches(model.attributes);
    });
} else {
    return this['filter'](function(model) {
        return matches(model.attributes);
    });
}
```

Which is the same as

```
if(first){
    return this.find(function(model) {
        return matches(model.attributes);
    });
} else {
    return this.filter(function(model) {
        return matches(model.attributes);
    });
}
```

I hope that clears it up.